# How does colcon install Python dependencies in ROS2?

Tags: ros, setup.py, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can Colcon with `ament_python` install dependencies from `setup.py` by itself during `colcon build --symlink-install` step? e.g. I would like pyserial to be automatically retrieved from pypi and installed without invoking pip3 manually:

```
setup(
...
   install_requires=['setuptools', 'pyserial']
...
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343575/how-does-colcon-install-python-dependencies-in-ros2?/) by [screen33](https://answers.ros.org/users/40664/screen33/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2020-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`colcon` doesn't install any dependencies (see the [docs](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/developer/design.html#explicitly-out-of-scope)). The expectations is that you have installed all necessary dependencies before you try to build a package (e.g. using `rosdep`).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [screen33](https://answers.ros.org/users/40664/screen33/) on 2020-02-07**:
Ah, yes. But it complains: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rosdep2'`. I do have multiple Python interpreters on this machine, however default is py3.6

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-02-07**:
You need to install dependencies for the specific Python version you are using. If you use Python 3.6 you need to have `python3-rosdep` installed. If you also have ROS 1 / `python-rosdep` installed it is sufficient to just install `python3-rosdep-modules` (all assuming you are on Ubuntu using the ROS apt repos).

**Comment by [screen33](https://answers.ros.org/users/40664/screen33/) on 2020-02-07**:
I also have ROS melodic, but I guess this is why I'm getting conflicts: `python3-rosdep : Depends: python3-catkin-pkg but it is not going to be installed`